# Asp.Net Web API - How to accept a file in a REST endpoint without using mutlipart?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to write a REST endpoint using the ASP.NET Web API framework. The use case is that the endpoint should be able to accept a stream of a zipped file.

The solutions that I have seen so far all use multipart/form-data but I'm trying to see whether it is possible to be able to do so without using multi-part.

Answer (score 0):

Use the multipart/form-data settings as a guide:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046

Comment: I'm trying to see whether there is something else that can be used besides multipart.